# Defining keywords for SQL using listings

Tags: listings, tcolorbox, code

**Problem:**

I use `listings` package to highlight `SQL` code but for some reason, unknown to me, I can't get certain keywords in `SQL` to highlight in a different color.

**Minimal Working Example:**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\definecolor{editorLightGray}{cmyk}{0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1}
\definecolor{editorWhite}{cmyk}{0, 0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{editorOrange}{cmyk}{0, 0.8, 1, 0}
\definecolor{editorBlue}{cmyk}{1, 0.6, 0, 0}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\newlength{\titleboxwidth}

\newtcolorbox{codelanguagebox}[2][]{boxrule=0pt,coltext=white,colback=labelPurple,arc=0pt,auto outer arc,width={#2},boxsep=0pt,left=5pt,right=5pt,halign=center,#1}

\NewDocumentCommand{\codelabel}{O{}mO{}}{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=0pt,boxsep=0pt,right=2.5pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt,colback=editorLightGray,arc=0pt,auto outer arc,#1]
    \setlength{\titleboxwidth}{\widthof{#2}}%
    \RaggedLeft\begin{codelanguagebox}[add to width=0.5cm,#3]{\the\titleboxwidth}
      \bfseries #2%
    \end{codelanguagebox}%
  \end{tcolorbox}   %
}

\lstdefinelanguage{php}{
        morestring=[s]{'}{'},
        morecomment=[l]{//},
        sensitive=false,
        keywords=[4]{athletics},
}

\lstset{%
    % Basic design
    backgroundcolor=\color{editorWhite},
    basicstyle={\footnotesize\ttfamily},   
    frame=l,
    % Line numbers
    xleftmargin={0cm},
    numbers=left,
    stepnumber=1,
    firstnumber=1,
    numberfirstline=true,
    % Code design
    identifierstyle=\color{editorOrange},
    keywordstyle=[1]\color{editorPink}\bfseries,
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{editorBlue}\bfseries,
    keywordstyle=[3]\color{editorBlack}\bfseries,
    keywordstyle=[4]\color{editorBlue}\bfseries,
    commentstyle=\color{editorGray}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{editorPurple},
    % Code
    language=php,
    alsodigit={.:;},
    tabsize=2,
    showtabs=false,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    extendedchars=true,
    breaklines=false,
    % Support for German umlauts
    literate=%
    {Ö}{{\"O}}1
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1
    {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {ß}{{\ss}}1
    {ü}{{\"u}}1
    {ä}{{\"a}}1
    {ö}{{\"o}}1
}

\begin{document}
    \codelabel[colback=editorLightGray]{\small\ttfamily SQL}[colback=editorOrange]
    \begin{lstlisting}
DROP DATABASE athletics;
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

**This code produce the following:**

[image]

**Desired outcome:**

The word "athletics" and all other predefined words should be in color blue.

Comment: Your example does not compile, and is a lot more complicated than it need to be. The problem here is that `alsodigit={.:;},` makes `athletics;` into a single construction. If you remove the `alsodigit` then it changes color. How to fix this, no idea at the moment, but I'd advise you to greatly simplify the MWE.

Comment: This seemed to be the solution. Now it changed color perfectly.

Comment: @daleif: Your comment was apparently the solution. Do you want to answer?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is that `alsodigit={.:;}` makes `athletics;` into a single entity with a single color.  Removing `alsodigit` seems to work.